# F#: How exactly is ToString supposed to be used?

Tags: f#

I am learning F# but I just don't understand how I am supposed to use ToString. Below are a few attempts. The syntax errors are saying it is expecting type string but that it is actually type uint -> string. So it doens't actually appear to be invoking a function? Could this be explained? This seems like such a simple thing to do but I can't figure it out.

```
open System
open System.IO
open FSharp.Data

[<EntryPoint>]
let main (args: string[]) =
    let htmlPage = HtmlDocument.Load("https://scrapethissite.com/")

    printfn  "%s" htmlPage.ToString // This causes a syntax error
    
    htmlPage.ToString
    |> (fun x -> printfn "%s" x) // This also causes a syntax error

    0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.ToString` is a method, not a value. In F# every method and every function has a parameter. In fact, that's how functions differ from values (and methods from properties): by having a parameter.

Unlike in C#, F# methods and functions cannot be parameterless. If there is nothing meaningful that you'd want to pass to the method, that method would still have one parameter of type `unit`. See how this is visible in the error message? `unit -> string` is the type.

To call such method, you have to pass it the parameter. The sole value of type `unit` is denoted `()`. So to call the method you should do:

```
    htmlPage.ToString ()
    |> printfn "%s"
```

Your first example is a bit more complicated. The following would not work:

```
printfn "%s" htmlPage.ToString ()
```

Why? Because according to F# syntax this looks like calling `printfn` and passing it three parameters: first `"%s"`, then `htmlPage.ToString`, and finally `()`. To get the correct order of calls you have to use parentheses:

```
printfn "%s" (htmlPage.ToString ())
```

---

And finally, general piece of advice: when possible try to avoid methods and classes in `F#` code. Most things can be done with functions. In this particular case, the `ToString`  methods can be replaced with the equivalent function `string`:

```
printfn "%s" (string htmlPage)
```

Comment: The cleanest way is using `"%O"` which implicitly calls `.ToString()`. Btw, to avoid many parentheses I often write `printfn "%s" <| htmlPage.ToString ()` sometimes it is easier to edit in one place (I don't need to find the place for the closing parenthesis).

Comment: another way would be to use `$"{htmlPage}"`